# Running .bat through Windows Services vs Startup Folder

Tags: batch-file, windows-services, startup-folder

The software(Java app) I'm working on is currently started through a batch file set up as a windows service, but it looks kind of a hassle to set it up for each computer, when I can just write a .bat file that creates a shortcut to the startup folder from a simple double-click. Are there any advantages to using windows services instead of the startup folder in windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service will run automatically when windows boots up and also restart automatically if the service fails.  You can manage service options by running services.msc

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755249.aspx

Comment: The restart is a nice feature, but it would take more than that to make me decide on which to use though

Comment: I suppose it depends on how often the app may crash, if you do or do not want it to restart automatically for troubleshooting purposes, and whether or not the users care about clicking the icon to reopen it.

Comment: You could also look into deploying the batch script to a list of computer names over the network.  Someone else would have to guide you further on that, but this may help:  http://serverfault.com/questions/248043/how-to-deploy-files-to-several-nodes-on-network-automatically

Comment: it's all machines from different networks. Basically I have a package for my software and when the user receives it, he has to set up the app to start on its own. So I'm looking for something simple.